# Windows setevent processing

Tags: c++, multithreading, events, join, c++11

I wonder how setevent is handled internally within Windows.

I have the following situation

Std::thread thread loop which executes while std::atomic  ==  true 
Inside the loop is a waitforsingleObject which sleeps infinite in alertable state.

A function stopThread() which does the following:
- Clears the atomic bool
- Calls Setevent on the event object
- Calls thread.join

This often hangs, I get the impression that setevent has still some work to do in the current thread, while join blocks 
the current thread.

If I add an additional Boolean in the thread which is set after waitforsinlgleObject and I wait for this to be set  before calling join() 
Everything seems to work ok.

Code (error checking omitted here)

Init code/declarations:

```
 HANDLE m_WakeupThreadEvent;
 std::atomic<bool> m_ReceiverEnabled;
 m_WakeupThreadEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, "RxThreadWakeupEvent" );
```

Thread code:

```
while(m_ReceiverEnabled)
{
    DWORD rslt = WaitForSingleObjectEx(m_WakeupThreadEvent, INFINITE, true);
    // Here some checking for rslt;
}
```

function code:

```
m_ReceiverEnabled = true;
SetEvent( m_WakeupThreadEvent )
m_Thread.join()
```

Is there some explanation for this behavior ? I could not find any details about the operation of setEvent()

Comment: Please show your code as well, reduced to just the threading portions. I expect you have a race condition: At the time you pulse the event, the thread has checked the `std::atomic` but has not begun waiting yet, and you're using an auto-reset event.

Comment: I added the code. I do not exepect a race condition. I happens in "passive state" where the thread is continuously sleeping, so not checking the bool.

Comment: Please include the creation of the event and the declaration of `m_ReceiverEnabled`

Comment: It definitely hangs on the WFSOE?  No in some queued APC completion routine that happens to be handled at the time?

Comment: I put a return early in the completion routine, so no significant code was executed. Also added a breakpoint after the WFSO statement, which seems not reached. Only a delay between setEvent and Join seems to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I just noticed: Why are you setting `m_ReceiverEnabled` to `true`? It should be set to `false`. I have done this in the code below.

Even if you're certain a race condition is not the root of your problem, you still have a race condition due to using an auto-reset event. Can you fix it, then see if that also happens to take care of your main problem as well? Here is code which uses a manual reset event instead in a race-free manner:

```
HANDLE m_WakeupThreadEvent;
std::atomic<bool> m_ReceiverEnabled;
m_WakeupThreadEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, "RxThreadWakeupEvent" );
```

---

```
m_ReceiverEnabled = false;
SetEvent( m_WakeupThreadEvent )
m_Thread.join()
```

---

```
while(true)
{
    DWORD rslt = WaitForSingleObjectEx(m_WakeupThreadEvent, INFINITE, true);
    ResetEvent(m_WakeupThreadEvent);
    if(!m_ReceiverEnabled)
        break;
    // Here some checking for rslt;
}
```

Comment: Changing it to manual reset event seem to fix the problem. The only thing I do not understand yet how how the auto reset event could create a race condition.

Comment: The thread must be actively waiting on an auto-reset event when it is pulsed or the pulse will be lost. I presume your thread was not, either because the event had been pulsed already and thus was somewhere in the while loop, or because you were in an APC.